# MongoDB Create New Document that references another Collection's Document IDs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a new document in the `Form` collection. This document references many `FormSection` documents. Here are the Schemas:

```
const FormSchema = new Schema({ 
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    sections: [{
        type: FormSectionDetails
    }],
    createdDate: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: true
    },
    lastEdited: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: true
    }
});

const FormSectionDetails = new Schema({
    section: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'FormSection',
        required: true
    },
    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const FormSectionSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    display: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
...
});

let FormSection;
try {
    FormSection = mongoose.connection.model('FormSection');
} catch (e) {
    FormSection = mongoose.model('FormSection', FormSectionSchema);
}
```

However, when I try to add a new document to the `Forms` collection, I get an error:

Document being inserted:

```
formData = {
    "title": "Returning Members",
    "description": "Returning Members",
    "sections": 
    [{
        "section": "6292c0fbd4837faca1d85d4d",
        "position": 1
    },
  {
        "section": "6292c0fbd4837faca1d85d4e",
        "position": 2
    },
...
}
```

Code being run:

```
formdata.sections.map(s => {
   return {
       ...s,
       section: ObjectId(s.section),
   }}
);
return await FormSection.create(formdata);
```

Error message:

`````
ValidationError: category: Path `category` is required., display: Path `display` is required.````

Seems like it is trying to create a new FormSection document. I don't want it to create a new FormSection document. I just want it to reference existing FormSection documents using the Object IDs I specified.
`````

Answer (score 1):

The Issue seems to be with how you declare the section field in the FormSchema. Try this:

```js
const FormSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  sections: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'FormSectionDetails',
    required: true,
  }],
  createdDate: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    unique: true
  },
  lastEdited: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    unique: true
  }
});
```

This would just store the _ids of the existing FormSectionDetails

Comment: I am still getting this error. It seems like MongoDB assumes I am trying to insert new `FormSection` documents, even though I just want to insert ObjectIDs of `FormSection` documents.

Comment: Thanks @Xanik, I have discovered the root cause (see my own answer). I really appreciate your answer, and the Schema you defined is correct. +1 upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was inserting the document into the wrong collection. Instead of the code snippet:

```
return await FormSection.create(formdata);
```

It should actually be:

```
return await Form.create(formdata);
```

The error message should have been a more obvious hint for me as to what the problem was.